# Problems configuring OpenVPN Server

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to set up OpenVPN Server.

I'm following the setup guide found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openvpn.html).  Everything works fine until I execute the `source vars` command. While I don't get an error, when I execute `./clean-all`.

I am told that  need to run source vars. I can't seem to get past this issue and can't continue until I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and run:

```
sudo su
```

before any of the steps in "Certificate Authority Setup".